# How have other languages overcame the limitations of Python's GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

As the industry trends to "web scale" application architecture (as much as I hate buzz words), I know Python has caught a lot of criticism for how the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) handles concurrency and becomes a bottleneck.  I understand the problem on the surface, but not well enough to know how other procedural languages handle threads under the hood.  Does Java have similar problems? C#? Ruby?  If not, why hasn't Python adopted the same strategy?

Comment: Nit: The GIL is an artifact of *CPython*; there is nothing inherent in the Python language that demands a GIL.

Comment: In fact, Jython and IIRC IronPython don't have a GIL and are as capable of multithreading as their underlying JVM/CLR.

Answer (score 7):

The GIL exists because it's needed (mainly) for CPython's implementation of reference counting - it's method of garbage collection. So let's be clear, *Python* doesn't have a GIL, the reference implementation does, and it's just an implementation detail.

The GIL exists because it makes the implementation simple and fast, and most of the time, it simply doesn't matter. Threading is mainly designed to allow access to slow resources alongside processing, which isn't hindered at all by the GIL.

The only reason that the GIL can be an issue is where one wants to do a lot of parallel computation. In this case, one can make an extension module in C or use the `multiprocessing` module to side-step the GIL.

All this means that the GIL really isn't an issue 99.9% of the time, and when it is, it's easily worked around. If you find it *really* hinders you, then you might want to try Jython, which is implemented on top of the JVM and uses a different method of garbage collection that doesn't require the GIL.

As always, premature optimization is a bad idea - if you develop something and find yourself hurt by the GIL, then there are ways to work around it without much pain. That said, it's highly unlikely you'll find it's a problem in the real-world. It's one of the most overblown things surrounding Python (maybe second only to the whole indentation thing).

Comment: It it's not just reference counting. One could add fine-grained (per-object) locks for refcounting (it's just awfully slow, at least without massive further changes), and a lot more than just refcounting isn't currently threadsafe because it relies on the GIL for synchronization.

Comment: @delnan Edited for a little more clarity.

Comment: I still wouldn't say *mainly* (and what this about the GC? Doesn't it "stop the world" anyway?). Probably half the methods of builtin objects would need locks if the GIL went away. And apart from that, you're not answering half of the question (what other languages do).

Comment: The *what other languages do* part of the question doesn't really suit SO, as it's very much a shopping list. I answered the more constructive part of the question.

Comment: I believe an answer to that needn't be a shopping list, there's basically just one other approach (lock less than the whole interpreter). I'd write an answer myself, but you already put the part about CPython's motivation quite well, and I'm not an expert on implementations of the other languages.